# Why doesn't foo := foo() result in an error?

Tags: go, syntax, compiler-errors

I'm trying to understand why in Go the following code does not produce an error.

```
func main() {
  foo := foo()
  fmt.Println(foo)
}

func foo() int {
  return 1 
}
```

Foo is already defined in the global scope, why am I able to redefine it ?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Comment: The same works in many (perhaps most) languages.

Answer (score 3):

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

> An identifier declared in a block may be redeclared in an inner
>   block. While the identifier of the inner declaration is in scope, it
>   denotes the entity declared by the inner declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to redeclare an identifier in an inner block.Program produces an error if the same identifier is declared twice in the same block.

Consider this example for understanding the scope:

```
package main
import "fmt"
var v="global"

func main() {
v := v
fmt.Println(v)

//v := v 
//Error: Same identifier 'v' declared again

{
v := "inner"
fmt.Println(v)  
}
fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Output of the Program:

```
global
inner
global
```